# Why won't my coins variable go up?

Tags: unity-game-engine

The script below controls a coins system. In another file, the coins is displayed on screen. But each collision, the coin does disappear because of Destroy(this.gameObject), but the coins variable doesn't increase. Why?

```
   #pragma strict
    var coins = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("coins");

    function OnTriggerEnter2D( other : Collider2D ) {
        coins += 1;
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("coins", coins); // or however many points you want to give per coin
        Destroy(this.gameObject);
    }
```

Comment: Try `PlayerPrefs.SetInt("coins", PlayerPrefs.GetInt("coins")+1);`

Comment: You really should be coding Unity in C# rather than javascript.

Answer (score 1):

You need to update your UI. You can do it by calling a method that update the value. Something similar to this:

```
textUI.updateCoins(coins);
```

And of course you should call it before your destroy method.